# How do I address the recent "Parse Error" when updating Google Contacts?

Tags: gdata, contacts, updating, bad-request

Starting around Feb 19th, 2014 I started receiving "Parse Error" when updating contacts through the GData  Contacts API. If I try again for the same entry it typically works but then appears for another contact. This same code worked for months with any changes. Anyone know what's up?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
 <error>
  <domain>GData</domain>
  <code>parseError</code>
  <internalReason>Parse Error</internalReason>
 </error>
</errors>
```

Answer (score 2):

parseError can happen when you don't set the Content-Type on your request to "application/atom+xml" (or "application/json" accordingly).